# Jenkins Error : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Process unexpectedly closed

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation

I am running automation scripts (Selenium-Java repository) with following setup -

> Selenium = 4.12.0,
> testng = 7.1.0,
> Amazon Corretto 17.0,
> Maven

Scripts runs perfectly fine at my local machine. But when I create Jenkins pipeline to run automation scripts, it's throws an error.
Jenkins server is in Azure cloud. I am using Kubernetes-docker infra from Azure. When I trigger build from Jenkins, I get following console logs from Jenkins -

```
INFO: Driver path: /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chromedriver

INFO: Browser path: /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome

[ERROR] Time elapsed: 12.406 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

please find below the selenium-Java code I was trying to run on Jenkins pipeline.

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class LoginWithChrome {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://google.co.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.quit();  
}
 }
```

Looking forward to your response. Thanks.